# Set console window size on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I know that there is a lot questions about how to set console size. But all found solutions are the same to my and my code doesn't works for me.

Ok, so for setting console window size, I need two functions. They are [SetConsoleScreenBufferSize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686044(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SetConsoleWindowInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686125(v=vs.85).aspx). First version of my function:

```
bool SetWindowSize(size_t width, size_t height)
{
    HANDLE output_handle = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(output_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    COORD coord = {};
    coord.X = static_cast<SHORT>(width);
    coord.Y = static_cast<SHORT>(height);
    if(::SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(output_handle, coord) == FALSE)
        return false;

    SMALL_RECT rect = {};
    rect.Bottom = coord.X - 1;
    rect.Right = coord.Y - 1;
    return (::SetConsoleWindowInfo(output_handle, TRUE, &rect) != FALSE);
}
```

`SetConsoleScreenBufferSize()` will work not for all values. From documentation:

> The specified width and height cannot be less than the width and
>   height of the console screen buffer's window

Lets try to get current window's size and call our function. To get window size, I need [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171(v=vs.85).aspx) function. main() test code:

```
HANDLE output_handle = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
if(output_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return 0;
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info = {};
if(::GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(output_handle, &info) == FALSE)
    return 0;
size_t width = info.srWindow.Right - info.srWindow.Left;
size_t height = info.srWindow.Bottom - info.srWindow.Top;
bool suc = SetWindowSize(width + 1, height + 1);
```

In this case `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize()` works fine. Next function is `SetConsoleWindowInfo()`. This function will work in case:

> The function fails if the specified window rectangle extends beyond
>   the boundaries of the console screen buffer. This means that the `Top`
>   and `Left` members of the `lpConsoleWindow` rectangle (or the calculated
>   top and left coordinates, if `bAbsolute` is FALSE) cannot be less than
>   zero. Similarly, the `Bottom` and `Right` members (or the calculated
>   bottom and right coordinates) cannot be greater than (screen buffer
>   `height – 1`) and (screen buffer `width – 1`), respectively. The function
>   also fails if the `Right` member (or calculated right coordinate) is
>   less than or equal to the `Left` member (or calculated left coordinate)
>   or if the `Bottom` member (or calculated bottom coordinate) is less than
>   or equal to the `Top` member (or calculated top coordinate).

In our case, the values of rectangle are the same (because `Left` and `Top` are zeroes) as values of `info.srWindow` rectangle after call of `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()`. But! `SetConsoleWindowInfo()` fails with next `::GetLastError()`

```
@err,hr ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER : The parameter is incorrect.   unsigned int
```

If I swap calls of this two functions:

```
bool SetWindowSize(size_t width, size_t height)
{
    HANDLE output_handle = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(output_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    SMALL_RECT rect = {};
    rect.Bottom = static_cast<SHORT>(width);
    rect.Right = static_cast<SHORT>(height);
    if(::SetConsoleWindowInfo(output_handle, TRUE, &rect) == FALSE)
        return false;

    COORD coord = {};
    coord.X = rect.Bottom + 1;
    coord.Y = rect.Right + 1;

    return (::SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(output_handle, coord) != FALSE);
}
```

then I will have the same error.

So, how can I use `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize()` and `SetConsoleWindowInfo()` correctly ?

Comment: `std::min` and `std::max` are nice functions. you can use them to compute relevant intermediate size of buffer and/or window. remember to define `NOMINMAX` before including `<windows.h>`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, your comment is not helpfull. I know how to use min and max functions. Tell me how to compute relevant intermediate size of buffer and/or window for succesfull use both functions for setting screen buffer size and window size

Comment: @veryexperienceduser: show me trivial example, that will work for me, please

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, are you there ?

Comment: oh. sorry i was away. no, i'm not going to code this up for you. but think about intersection and union of rectangles. that's what it's about: you can't reduce buffer size to less than window, because then there would be display areas with no data, and for the same reason you can't increase window to more than buffer size. so for window resizing you just have to make the buffer large enough, and position the window (view) appropriately wrt. the buffer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61497/discussion-between-user2451677-and-cheers-and-hth-alf).

Comment: no, i'm not going to do your work for you in chat or here or anywhere. stop whining, stop trying to get others to do stuff for you, and get going.

Comment: This looks suspicious to me: `rect.Bottom = coord.X - 1;` and `rect.Right = coord.Y - 1;` also `rect.Bottom = static_cast<SHORT>(width);` and `rect.Right = static_cast<SHORT>(height);`. Is it your intention to swap to width/heights as passed to the function before then trying to adjust the window size?

Comment: @enhzflep, I can't understand your question. To use `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize()`, I need to use `COORD` struct, where `X` is width and `Y` is height. For `rect` - I'm specifying upper-left and lower-right corners of the window

Comment: You didn't ask this question the Smart Way, just giving pieces of the code with little chance that anybody can put them back together and repro the problem.  There's another restriction, the console buffer size cannot be larger than 64KB.  Whether that's relevant is impossible to tell from the question.

Comment: @user2451677 - you're setting the `rect.bottom` to be the `width` and your setting `rect.right` to be the `height`. Lines 14 and 15 of your first snippet. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 6):

SetConsoleWindowInfo() does not reposition the console window on the screen. The name of this function is misleading. It rather **scrolls** the current visible portion inside the console window. See [this sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) here.

If you want to set the position of a console window that runs your programm, use code such as:

```
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
RECT rect = {100, 100, 300, 500};
MoveWindow(hwnd, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right-rect.left, rect.bottom-rect.top,TRUE);
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by making these functions which can get/set the console window/buffer sizes *in characters* taking into account increasing the buffer size if needed, console font size, window borders and all that jazz.

The variables at play here to understand:

- Windows have a *client area*, which is the coordinates (in pixels) excluding the borders
- Windows have a *window area*, which is the coordinates (in pixels) including the borders
- Console has a *view area*, which is the window size in characters
- Console has a *screen buffer*, which is the scrollable buffer size in characters
- Console has a *font size*, which is the character size in coordinates (pixels)
- Console's *screen buffer* cannot be smaller than the *view area*

You need to correctly mix and match these around to achieve the desired result.

**These functions are plug-n-play so you don't need to worry about none of that though.**

All functions return TRUE (1) on success and FALSE (0) on error.

#### Set Console Window Size

```cpp
static BOOL SetConsoleSize(int cols, int rows) {
  HWND hWnd;
  HANDLE hConOut;
  CONSOLE_FONT_INFO fi;
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bi;
  int w, h, bw, bh;
  RECT rect = {0, 0, 0, 0};
  COORD coord = {0, 0};
  hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
  if (hWnd) {
    hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hConOut && hConOut != (HANDLE)-1) {
      if (GetCurrentConsoleFont(hConOut, FALSE, &fi)) {
        if (GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect)) {
          w = rect.right-rect.left;
          h = rect.bottom-rect.top;
          if (GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect)) {
            bw = rect.right-rect.left-w;
            bh = rect.bottom-rect.top-h;
            if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConOut, &bi)) {
              coord.X = bi.dwSize.X;
              coord.Y = bi.dwSize.Y;
              if (coord.X < cols || coord.Y < rows) {
                if (coord.X < cols) {
                  coord.X = cols;
                }
                if (coord.Y < rows) {
                  coord.Y = rows;
                }
                if (!SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hConOut, coord)) {
                  return FALSE;
                }
              }
              return SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, rect.left, rect.top, cols*fi.dwFontSize.X+bw, rows*fi.dwFontSize.Y+bh, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}

/* usage */
SetConsoleSize(80, 40);
```

#### Get Console Window Size

```cpp
static BOOL GetConsoleSize(int* cols, int* rows) {
  HWND hWnd;
  HANDLE hConOut;
  CONSOLE_FONT_INFO fi;
  int w, h;
  RECT rect = {0, 0, 0, 0};
  hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
  if (hWnd) {
    hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hConOut && hConOut != (HANDLE)-1) {
      if (GetCurrentConsoleFont(hConOut, FALSE, &fi)) {
        if (GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect)) {
          w = rect.right-rect.left;
          h = rect.bottom-rect.top;
          *cols = w / fi.dwFontSize.X;
          *rows = h / fi.dwFontSize.Y;
          return TRUE;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}

/* usage */
int cols, rows;
GetConsoleSize(&cols, &rows);
```

#### Set Console Buffer Size

```cpp
static BOOL SetConsoleBufferSize(int cols, int rows) {
  HANDLE hConOut;
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bi;
  COORD coord = {0, 0};
  hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  if (hConOut && hConOut != (HANDLE)-1) {
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConOut, &bi)) {
      coord.X = cols;
      coord.Y = rows;
      return SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hConOut, coord);
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}

/* usage */
SetConsoleBufferSize(80, 300);
```

#### Get Console Buffer Size

```cpp
static BOOL GetConsoleBufferSize(int* cols, int* rows) {
  HANDLE hConOut;
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bi;
  hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  if (hConOut && hConOut != (HANDLE)-1) {
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConOut, &bi)) {
      *cols = bi.dwSize.X;
      *rows = bi.dwSize.Y;
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}

/* usage */
int cols, rows;
GetConsoleBufferSize(&cols, &rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [TurboVision port](http://oscada.org/svn/trunk/ComplexCfg/tv/SOURCE/tscreen.cpp):

```
void TDisplay::setCrtMode( ushort mode )
{
  int oldr = getRows();
  int oldc = getCols();
  int cols = uchar(mode >> 8);
  int rows = uchar(mode);
  if ( cols == 0 ) cols = oldc;
  if ( rows == 0 ) rows = oldr;
  checksize(rows, cols);
  COORD newSize = { cols, rows };
  SMALL_RECT rect = { 0, 0, cols-1, rows-1 };

  if ( oldr <= rows )
  {
    if ( oldc <= cols )
    {                           // increasing both dimensions
BUFWIN:
      SetConsoleScreenBufferSize( TThreads::chandle[cnOutput], newSize );
      SetConsoleWindowInfo( TThreads::chandle[cnOutput], True, &rect );
    }
    else
    {                           // cols--, rows+
      SMALL_RECT tmp = { 0, 0, cols-1, oldr-1 };
      SetConsoleWindowInfo( TThreads::chandle[cnOutput], True, &tmp );
      goto BUFWIN;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if ( oldc <= cols )
    {                           // cols+, rows--
      SMALL_RECT tmp = { 0, 0, oldc-1, rows-1 };
      SetConsoleWindowInfo( TThreads::chandle[cnOutput], True, &tmp );
      goto BUFWIN;
    }
    else
    {                           // cols--, rows--
      SetConsoleWindowInfo( TThreads::chandle[cnOutput], True, &rect );
      SetConsoleScreenBufferSize( TThreads::chandle[cnOutput], newSize );
    }
  }
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( TThreads::chandle[cnOutput], &TThreads::sbInfo );
}

ushort TDisplay::getRows()
{
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( TThreads::chandle[cnOutput], &TThreads::sbInfo );
  return TThreads::sbInfo.dwSize.Y;
}

ushort TDisplay::getCols()
{
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( TThreads::chandle[cnOutput], &TThreads::sbInfo );
  return TThreads::sbInfo.dwSize.X;
}
```

Comment: Set the window size before the buffer so that you don't make the buffer smaller than the window resulting in a function failure.