# Size of the console window using the Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

I am trying to make a console tetris game. But have problem about the setting the window size of console.

I am using `SetConsoleWindowInfo()` method to resize the window. But it looks does not work. It changes only when I changed the console launch size on the setting of Command Prompt.

CODE :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int nScreenWidth = 80;
int nScreenHeight = 30;

int main() {

    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SMALL_RECT windowSize = { 0, 0, (SHORT)nScreenWidth, (SHORT)nScreenHeight };
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &windowSize);

    while (true)
    {
        
    }

}
```

COMMAND PROMPT SETTINGS

400 * 400 Window Size:
[image: 400 * 400 Window Size]

When I run the program, console window's size is the size from settings.
Changing `nScreenWidth` or `nScreenHeight` changes nothing.

How can I change the size with using `SetConsoleWindowInfo()`?
Or there is any different method?

Comment: Hi, have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912721/set-console-window-size-on-windows) ?

Comment: Yes. I did but does not work. Thanks. Btw i use win11.

Comment: Consider error-handling for SetConsoleWindowInfo(). If functions fail, evaluating the returned error codes is typically the very first debugging step.

Comment: Function does not fail. Returns 1.

Comment: On Win11 the new "Windows Terminal" is the default console app and it looks like this app currently [doesn't support resizing by code](https://superuser.com/questions/1778402/dynamically-change-terminal-window-size-on-win11) at all. SetConsoleWindowInfo() is known to do nothing (no change, no error) in this scenario.

Comment: This API does not have a virtual terminal equivalent. So it's not recommended to use this API in windows terminal. You can see ecosystem roadmap.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ecosystem-roadmap