Resizing a console window not working-Windows C
I am making a console game and need the console to be a specific size. I have looked at various methods such as SetWindowsPos, MoveWindow, SetConsoleScreenBufferSize but neither of them have worked. SetWindowPos and MoveWindow seem to do nothing to change the size (I checked to make sure the functions weren't returning an error value) and SetConsoleScreenBufferSize doesn't change the actual console windows size.
Any ideas on where to go?

Consoles have their own messages for setting the size, but I can't remember them offhand.  The buffer size is not related to the window size, so that's not it.

MoveWindow works for me. Perhaps you should show us the code that isn't working. I used this code to test MoveWindow https://stackoverflow.com/a/36983796/920069

Does this answer your question? Set console window size on Windows

Are you using the legacy console or the new Windows Terminal? If it's the latter you're not the first to hit a wall.

@Halfix Yes you were right.  I had been using the new terminal. I just tried the exact same code on an older version and it works fine. I never thought the issue would be with windows version. Thanks for the help!

Please show your solution by creating an answer post, instead of editing it into the question.

You should have your program spawn it's own console window rather than running in the parent environment from which it was spawned.  That way it should not matter whether you were running from cmd, Windows Terminal, PowerShell, or running from Explorer.  The version of Windows should make no difference all those methods of launching still exist.

Solution: The issue was nothing to do with my code. A fellow programmer in the comments spotted that Windows 11 Terminal does not support console resizing. Trying my same code on an older version of Windows worked perfectly fine.

Apparently the console is still available in Win 11, but you have to choose between Windows Terminal or Windows Console prior to runtime of your app.
